# Grab value from javascript object and store it into Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am getting input values of form using this method

```
var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
```

and when i use console.log(fields); it print the following input

```
[Object { name="chkoptions[]",  value="3"}, Object { name="chkoptions[]",  value="22"}]
```

I want to grab value from this object and store them in another array to post all values using ajax post , how i get value attribute from this object

Answer (score 2):

```
fields.forEach(function(field) {
    someArray.push(field.value);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a javascript based solution if you don't want to use jQuery ;-)

```
var secondArray = [];
var fields = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

for(var i = 0 ; i < fields.length ; i++){
    secondArray[i] = fields[i].value;
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm getting the form elements using `getElementsByTagName("input")` but you can use the method you want.

Comment: mine isnt JQuery ;-) ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

While the `forEach` method will do the job, the best method actually, given the fact that you have an input array and you want to get a transformed array as output, would be to use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

So the following code

```
var transformedFields = fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.value;
});
```

will give you the desired array of values extracted from your `fields` array.